# Numbering poems stanzas using roman numerals

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting, text, numbering

I would be able to numbering, sequentially, any stanza of a certain poem using roman numerals like this:

```
       
       Injurious love, why still to mar accord
       Between desires has been thy favourite feat?
       Why does it please thee so, perfidious lord,
       Two hearts should with a different measure beat?
       Thou wilt not let me take the certain ford,
       Dragging me where the stream is deep and fleet.
       Her I abandon who my love desires,
       While she who hates, respect and love inspires.
       
       Thou to Rinaldo show'st the damsel fair,
       While he seems hideous to that gentle dame;
       And he, who when the lady's pride and care,
       Paid back with deepest hate her amorous flame,
       Now pines, himself, the victim of despair,
       Scorned in his turn, and his reward the same.
       By the changed damsel in such sort abhorred,
       She would choose death before that hated lord.
       
       He to the Pagan cries: "Forego thy theft,
       And down, false felon, from that pilfer'd steed;
       I am not wont to let my own be reft.
       And he who seeks it dearly pays the deed.
       More -- I shall take from thee yon lovely weft;
       To leave thee such a prize were foul misdeed;
       And horse and maid, whose worth outstrips belief,
       Were ill, methinks, relinquished to a thief."
       
       "Thou liest," the haughty Saracen retorts,
       As proud, and burning with as fierce a flame,
       "A thief thyself, if Fame the truth reports:
       But let good deeds decide our dubious claim,
       With whom the steed or damsel fair assorts:
       Best proved by valiant deeds: though, for the dame,
       That nothing is so precious, I with thee
       (Search the wide world throughout) may well agree."
```

Into this: with roman capital numbers aligned to the last verse of stanza?

```
       Injurious love, why still to mar accord
       Between desires has been thy favourite feat?
       Why does it please thee so, perfidious lord,
       Two hearts should with a different measure beat?
       Thou wilt not let me take the certain ford,
       Dragging me where the stream is deep and fleet.
       Her I abandon who my love desires,
I      While she who hates, respect and love inspires.
       
       Thou to Rinaldo show'st the damsel fair,
       While he seems hideous to that gentle dame;
       And he, who when the lady's pride and care,
       Paid back with deepest hate her amorous flame,
       Now pines, himself, the victim of despair,
       Scorned in his turn, and his reward the same.
       By the changed damsel in such sort abhorred,
II     She would choose death before that hated lord.
       
       He to the Pagan cries: "Forego thy theft,
       And down, false felon, from that pilfer'd steed;
       I am not wont to let my own be reft.
       And he who seeks it dearly pays the deed.
       More -- I shall take from thee yon lovely weft;
       To leave thee such a prize were foul misdeed;
       And horse and maid, whose worth outstrips belief,
III    Were ill, methinks, relinquished to a thief."
       
       "Thou liest," the haughty Saracen retorts,
       As proud, and burning with as fierce a flame,
       "A thief thyself, if Fame the truth reports:
       But let good deeds decide our dubious claim,
       With whom the steed or damsel fair assorts:
       Best proved by valiant deeds: though, for the dame,
       That nothing is so precious, I with thee
IV     (Search the wide world throughout) may well agree."
```

I wonder if there are any way to make this in linux with text utilities. It maybe can be not suitable for awk, generating numerals in roman style, but I already found somewhere on internet a bash script to generate roman numerals

```
#/bin/bash
# roman.sh
#
#   Function
#
    num2roman() { # NUM
    # Returns NUM in roman letters
    #
        input=$1    # input num
        output=""   # Clear output string
        len=${#input}   # Initial length to count down
        
        roman_val() { # NUM one five ten
        # This sub does the basic 'roman' algorythm
        #
            N=$1
            one=$2
            five=$3
            ten=$4
            out=""
            
            case $N in
            0)  out+="" ;;
            [123])  while [[ $N -gt 0 ]]
                do  out+="$one"
                    N=$(($N-1))
                done
                ;;
            4)  out+="$one$five"    ;;
            5)  out+="$five"    ;;
            [678])  out+="$five"
                N=$(($N-5))
                while [[ $N -gt 0 ]]
                do  out+="$one"
                    N=$(($N-1))
                done
                ;;
            9)  while [[ $N -lt 10 ]]
                do  out+="$one"
                    N=$(($N+1))
                done
                out+="$ten"
                ;;
            esac
            echo $out
        }
        
        while [[ $len -gt 0  ]]
        do  # There are letters to add
            num=${input:0:1}
            # Do action according position
            case $len in
            1)  # 1
                output+="$(roman_val $num I V X)"
                ;;
            2)  # 10
                output+="$(roman_val $num X L C)"
                ;;
            3)  # 100
                output+="$(roman_val $num C D M)"
                ;;
            *)  # 1000+
                # 10'000 gets a line above, 100'000 gets a line on the left.. how to?
                num=${input:0:(-3)}
                while [[ $num -gt 0 ]]
                do  output+="M"
                    num=$(($num-1))
                done
                
                ;;
            esac
            input=${input:1} ; len=${#input}
        done
        echo $output
    }
#
#   Call it
#
    num2roman $1
```

That I invoke with this syntax:

```
 for N in `seq 1 10`;do ./roman.sh $N; done
```

Whose output is:

```
I
II
III
IV
V
VI
VII
VIII
IX
X
```

So, from another point of view, it could be only matter of picking, from generated roman numerals list, any item and then put any of these aligned with the last verse of any stanza

Comment: Is the poem already indented, or the poem is align to the beginning of the line and you would like the solution to add the indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be simpler to print the record number on a new line after each block. If your blank lines are completely blank (i.e. they are `\n\n` rather than `\n       \n`), then AWK's "paragraph mode" (empty string as `RS`) can be used:

```c
function d2r(n,    m) {
    m = sprintf("%*s", int(n/1000), "")
    gsub(/ /, "M", m)
    return m r100[int(n%1000/100)] r10[int(n%100/10)] r1[int(n%10)]
}

BEGIN {
    split("C,CC,CCC,CD,D,DC,DCC,DCCC,CM", r100, ",")
    split("X,XX,XXX,XL,L,LX,LXX,LXXX,XC", r10, ",")
    split("I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX", r1, ",")

    RS = ""
}

{
    print
    print d2r(NR) " (" NR ")"
    print ""
}
```

above is saved as `roman_numeral_blocks.awk`

```
$ printf '%s\n\n' foo bar | awk -f roman_numeral_blocks.awk
foo
I (1) 

bar
II (2)
```

The `" (" NR ")"` part is so that you can verify `d2r()` produced the correct result. `d2r()` tries to produce a Roman numeral for a given decimal number. "M" is simply repeated for every lot of 1000.

If you want the number printed on the same line as the last line of the block, then you'll have to work out how to keep the original indentation, and what to do when the space available in the margin is less than the space required to print the number.

To apply the above to the OPs example, using any POSIX awk, would be:

```
$ cat roman_numeral_blocks.awk
function d2r(n,    m) {
    m = sprintf("%*s", int(n/1000), "")
    gsub(/ /, "M", m)
    return m r100[int(n%1000/100)] r10[int(n%100/10)] r1[int(n%10)]
}

BEGIN {
    split("C,CC,CCC,CD,D,DC,DCC,DCCC,CM", r100, ",")
    split("X,XX,XXX,XL,L,LX,LXX,LXXX,XC", r10, ",")
    split("I,II,III,IV,V,VI,VII,VIII,IX", r1, ",")
}

NR > 1 { prt(0) }
{ prev = $0 }
END { prt(1) }

function prt(isEnd,     pfx) {
    if ( (!NF || isEnd) && (match(prev, /[^[:space:]]/)) ) {
        prev = substr(prev, RSTART)
        pfx = sprintf("%-*s", RSTART-1, d2r(++numParas) " ")
    }
    print pfx prev
}
```

```
$ awk -f roman_numeral_blocks.awk file

       Injurious love, why still to mar accord
       Between desires has been thy favourite feat?
       Why does it please thee so, perfidious lord,
       Two hearts should with a different measure beat?
       Thou wilt not let me take the certain ford,
       Dragging me where the stream is deep and fleet.
       Her I abandon who my love desires,
I      While she who hates, respect and love inspires.

       Thou to Rinaldo show'st the damsel fair,
       While he seems hideous to that gentle dame;
       And he, who when the lady's pride and care,
       Paid back with deepest hate her amorous flame,
       Now pines, himself, the victim of despair,
       Scorned in his turn, and his reward the same.
       By the changed damsel in such sort abhorred,
II     She would choose death before that hated lord.

       He to the Pagan cries: "Forego thy theft,
       And down, false felon, from that pilfer'd steed;
       I am not wont to let my own be reft.
       And he who seeks it dearly pays the deed.
       More -- I shall take from thee yon lovely weft;
       To leave thee such a prize were foul misdeed;
       And horse and maid, whose worth outstrips belief,
III    Were ill, methinks, relinquished to a thief."

       "Thou liest," the haughty Saracen retorts,
       As proud, and burning with as fierce a flame,
       "A thief thyself, if Fame the truth reports:
       But let good deeds decide our dubious claim,
       With whom the steed or damsel fair assorts:
       Best proved by valiant deeds: though, for the dame,
       That nothing is so precious, I with thee
IV     (Search the wide world throughout) may well agree."
```

Comment: First, in your `d2r` function, you do not need the `m` argument; `m` is a local variable of the function. But more importantly, you didn't follow the request of the OP: The roman capital numbers should be **aligned to the last verse of stanza**, not **between** the paragraphs as you did.  I suggest (assuming that the poem is already indented): `!NF {roman = d2r(++c); print roman substr(prev, length(roman)+1); prev=" "} NF {if (prev) print prev; prev=$0} END {roman = d2r(++c); print roman substr(prev, length(roman)+1)}`.

Comment: @aviro specifying `m` in the argument list (idiomatically preceeded with a lot of white space to tell us why it's there) is how to **make** `m` a function-local local variable, otherwise `m` is a global variable.

Comment: this works well. Can the roman numerals be right aligned instead of left aligned?

Comment: @Dingo - in the `prt()` function the prefix is formatted with `%-*s` - to right-align, change that to `%*s`.

Answer (score 1):

The following perl script uses the perl [Roman](https://metacpan.org/release/Roman) module.  Depending on what kind of unix you're using, this may be available pre-packaged for your OS. e.g. on Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu or Mint, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install libroman-perl`.  Other Linux distributions may have similarly named packages.  Otherwise, install it with `cpan`:

```
$ perl -MRoman -00 -ne '
    @para = split /\n/, $_;
    foreach my $l (0..$#para-1) {
      $para[$l] = sprintf "%6s  %s", "", $para[$l]
    };

    $para[$#para] = sprintf "%6s  %s", roman(++$stanza), $para[$#para];

    print join("\n", @para),"\n\n"' poem2.txt 
        Injurious love, why still to mar accord
        Between desires has been thy favourite feat?
        Why does it please thee so, perfidious lord,
        Two hearts should with a different measure beat?
        Thou wilt not let me take the certain ford,
        Dragging me where the stream is deep and fleet.
        Her I abandon who my love desires,
     i  While she who hates, respect and love inspires.

        Thou to Rinaldo show'st the damsel fair,
        While he seems hideous to that gentle dame;
        And he, who when the lady's pride and care,
        Paid back with deepest hate her amorous flame,
        Now pines, himself, the victim of despair,
        Scorned in his turn, and his reward the same.
        By the changed damsel in such sort abhorred,
    ii  She would choose death before that hated lord.

        He to the Pagan cries: "Forego thy theft,
        And down, false felon, from that pilfer'd steed;
        I am not wont to let my own be reft.
        And he who seeks it dearly pays the deed.
        More -- I shall take from thee yon lovely weft;
        To leave thee such a prize were foul misdeed;
        And horse and maid, whose worth outstrips belief,
   iii  Were ill, methinks, relinquished to a thief."

        "Thou liest," the haughty Saracen retorts,
        As proud, and burning with as fierce a flame,
        "A thief thyself, if Fame the truth reports:
        But let good deeds decide our dubious claim,
        With whom the steed or damsel fair assorts:
        Best proved by valiant deeds: though, for the dame,
        That nothing is so precious, I with thee
    iv  (Search the wide world throughout) may well agree."
```

This reads in the file in paragraph mode (paragraph boundaries are one-or-more empty lines), splits each paragraph into an array (`@para`), and indents all but the last line of @para with 8 spaces.  The last line of @para is indented by a 6-character wide roman numeral indicating the stanza number and another two spaces.  The array is then printed.

For upper-case Roman numerals, use the `uc` function with the `roman()` function - i.e. replace the **second** line containing `sprintf` with:

```
$para[$#para] = sprintf "%6s  %s", uc(roman(++$stanza)), $para[$#para];
```

and if you want the roman numerals left-aligned, use `%-6s`.  e.g.

```
$para[$#para] = sprintf "%-6s  %s", roman(++$stanza), $para[$#para];
```

or

```
$para[$#para] = sprintf "%-6s  %s", uc(roman(++$stanza)), $para[$#para];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MMath::Roman -e '
 my @para = .split( /^^ \h**7 "\n" /, :skip-empty ) given slurp;
 for @para.kv -> $k,$v { "\n".print; for $v.lines.kv -> $l_key,$l_value {
 put(sprintf( "%*s  ", 5, "{to-roman($k+1) if $l_key == 7}") ~ "{$l_value.trim-leading}")
 };};' Ariosto.txt
```

Sample Input (copy-pasted directly out of OP's post, above):

```
   Injurious love, why still to mar accord
   Between desires has been thy favourite feat?
   Why does it please thee so, perfidious lord,
   Two hearts should with a different measure beat?
   Thou wilt not let me take the certain ford,
   Dragging me where the stream is deep and fleet.
   Her I abandon who my love desires,
   While she who hates, respect and love inspires.
   
   Thou to Rinaldo show'st the damsel fair,
   While he seems hideous to that gentle dame;
   And he, who when the lady's pride and care,
   Paid back with deepest hate her amorous flame,
   Now pines, himself, the victim of despair,
   Scorned in his turn, and his reward the same.
   By the changed damsel in such sort abhorred,
   She would choose death before that hated lord.
   
   He to the Pagan cries: "Forego thy theft,
   And down, false felon, from that pilfer'd steed;
   I am not wont to let my own be reft.
   And he who seeks it dearly pays the deed.
   More -- I shall take from thee yon lovely weft;
   To leave thee such a prize were foul misdeed;
   And horse and maid, whose worth outstrips belief,
   Were ill, methinks, relinquished to a thief."
   
   "Thou liest," the haughty Saracen retorts,
   As proud, and burning with as fierce a flame,
   "A thief thyself, if Fame the truth reports:
   But let good deeds decide our dubious claim,
   With whom the steed or damsel fair assorts:
   Best proved by valiant deeds: though, for the dame,
   That nothing is so precious, I with thee
   (Search the wide world throughout) may well agree."
```

Sample Output:

```
       Injurious love, why still to mar accord
       Between desires has been thy favourite feat?
       Why does it please thee so, perfidious lord,
       Two hearts should with a different measure beat?
       Thou wilt not let me take the certain ford,
       Dragging me where the stream is deep and fleet.
       Her I abandon who my love desires,
    I  While she who hates, respect and love inspires.

       Thou to Rinaldo show'st the damsel fair,
       While he seems hideous to that gentle dame;
       And he, who when the lady's pride and care,
       Paid back with deepest hate her amorous flame,
       Now pines, himself, the victim of despair,
       Scorned in his turn, and his reward the same.
       By the changed damsel in such sort abhorred,
   II  She would choose death before that hated lord.

       He to the Pagan cries: "Forego thy theft,
       And down, false felon, from that pilfer'd steed;
       I am not wont to let my own be reft.
       And he who seeks it dearly pays the deed.
       More -- I shall take from thee yon lovely weft;
       To leave thee such a prize were foul misdeed;
       And horse and maid, whose worth outstrips belief,
  III  Were ill, methinks, relinquished to a thief."

       "Thou liest," the haughty Saracen retorts,
       As proud, and burning with as fierce a flame,
       "A thief thyself, if Fame the truth reports:
       But let good deeds decide our dubious claim,
       With whom the steed or damsel fair assorts:
       Best proved by valiant deeds: though, for the dame,
       That nothing is so precious, I with thee
   IV  (Search the wide world throughout) may well agree."
```

The Raku code above is fairly robust to pre-existing indentation, and the `split` code can be adjusted to accommodate different spacing between adjacent stanzas, as described (below).

Briefly, The poetry file is `slurp`-ed in and `split` into `@para` paragraphs using the `/^^ \h**7 "\n" /` regex, which looks for the pattern 1) `^^` start-of-line, 2) `\h**7` seven horizontal whitespaces and 3) a `\n` newline. [If the lines separating stanzas are truly empty, use `/^^ $$ "\n" /` as the regex]. The `split` function is instructed to drop empty strings via the parameter/adverb `:skip-empty`, leaving 4 paragraphs (i.e stanzas). Paragraphs are numbered with `kv` key-value and first passed into a `for` loop, then passed into a nested `for` loop. Within the nested `for` loop the `$v` value (i.e. text) is broken into (8) `lines`, and numbered 0-to-7 with `kv` (used below for numbering each stanza).

Printing is accomplished by `put`, which calls `sprintf` to format the `$k+1` paragraph number as a string, followed by the`$l_value` (text) string. Strings are concatenated with `~`.  Paragraph numbering is accomplished using the three-element, minimum-width (right-justified) string formatter: `sprintf( "%*s  ", 5, "{to-roman($k+1) if $l_key == 7}")`. The `if` conditional places numbering only on the `$l_key == 7` (zero-indexed seventh) line of the paragraph. Since indentation accomplished with `sprintf`, each line of the `$l_value` poem needs to be trimmed using `trim-leading`, so that output aligns properly.

Finally, the `to-roman(…)` sub converts the `$k+1` paragraph counter to Roman Numeral, using the `Math::Roman` module called at the command-line with `-M`. [In fact, the postfix `(…)R` also works here]. Raku modules can be searched at https://modules.raku.org and installed with `zef`, see: https://github.com/ugexe/zef .

References:
https://modules.raku.org/dist/Math::Roman:cpan:TITSUKI
https://raku.org